# How to convert strings to ints in a nested list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

When I try this code:

```
listy = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], "abc"]

for item in listy[0]:
    int(item)
    
print(listy)
```

I get this result:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'abc']
```

I.e., the list is not changed. Why is that? How can I change all those `str`s to `int`s in the nested list?

Comment: `int(item)` <-- a value is computed and then *discarded*. Put it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the converted items back to the sub-list (`listy[0]`):

```
listy[0][:] = [int(x) for x in listy[0]]
```

Explanation:

```
for item in listy[0]:
    int(item)
```

The above iterates over the items in the sub-list and converts them to integers, but it does not assign the result of the expression `int(item)` to anything. Therefore the result is lost.

`[int(x) for x in listy[0]]` is a list comprehension (kind of shorthand for your `for` loop) that iterates over the list, converting each item to an integer and returning a new list. The new list is then assigned back (in place, optional) to the outer list.

This is a very custom solution for your specific question. A more general solution involves recursion to get at the sub-lists, and some way of detecting the candidates for numeric conversion.

Comment: thanks! could you explain how this statement works if you don't mind? I'm just learning python in class

Comment: @pearbear: updated with some explanation.